# Diference between these sentences

Tags: tense, present-perfect

I have to correct this sentence :
*I gave up drinking coffee. I don't drink it for a year.*
An answer should be at present perfect or present perfect continuous.
I think the answer is "I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't been drinking coffee for a year." but the right answer is "I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't drunk." by the book's keys at the end of this book.
What is difference of these sentences and are they correct both ?

Comment: "I haven't been drinking coffee for a year" is correct usage, but after "I gave up drinking coffee", the correct version is "I haven't drunk it for a year". Both are grammatically correct but the book's answer is the one that I would use as a native speaker.

Comment: This can also be said in this way: "I gave up drinking coffee. I have not had coffee in a year."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would both be understood as intended, I think. But your answer could potentially be misunderstood.

The issue is that

> I haven't been drinking coffee for a year.

can suggest that the speaker has not been *continuously engaged* in drinking coffee for a period of a year-- they have not been constantly drinking coffee for 365 days. What you want to express is that you have, for a year, been *not drinking* coffee, but that's an awkward construction due to the negation.

Use of *drunk* eliminates this ambiguity. At no point in the last year did you drink coffee, whether with a defined completion or otherwise.

It's probably good for a book used in learning English to minimize potential confusion, and so I think it makes sense to mark the sentence using *drunk* as the *most* correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

*"I gave up drinking coffee. I don't drink it for a year"* Yes, this is grammatically incorrect, as you said.

You can combine both "I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't been drinking coffee for a year" and "I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't drunk" into "I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't drank it in/for a year" to create a more natural sounding sentence.

In the sentence that you have stated that you think is correct (I gave up drinking coffee. I haven't been drinking coffee for a year), it is better to use the object pronoun 'it' in place of repeating 'coffee' because we already know what the noun is, so repeating it sounds odd.

Hope this helps

Comment: "I haven't drank it for a year" really isn't right. It should be "... haven't *drunk* it ..." Even though lots of people say "have drank", lots of people also know it's bad English and sounds ugly.